# Why click function triggers twice for custom component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, mouseevent, angular2-custom-component

My custom component `click` function is triggered twice - both custom component's event and sample level event are triggered.

Here's my Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wp2iWh7OStdPm5uXsWbP?p=preview

Answer (score 22):

Because you have bound it twice on the child component and on the parent component. The `mouseEvent` propagates from the child component to the parent component by default. You can stop propagation of event to parent component.

### Template:

```html
<div (click)="divClick($event)">Custom Div Clcik here!</div>
```

### Class:

```js
divClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("divClick");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you call click() event on your parent component and in your child component:
here:

```
<cus-div (click)="onClick()"></cus-div>
```

and here:

```
<div (click)="divClick()">Custom Div Clcik here!</div>
```

remove the click event on your `<cus-div></cus-div>` of your click event and it will trigger once

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar issue, i found the solution for mine, i had two `*ngIf`, one negated, to swap a icon in my case. I replaced `*ngIf` with `[hidden]` (display: none;).

Answer (score 0):

my believe is: add emit solves it as well

***Template***

```
<div (click)="divClick($event)">Custom Div Clcik here!</div>
```

***Class***

```
@Output()
divClick = new EventEmitter<any>().emit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

instead of:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```