# Creating a reusable button component in Angular

Tags: angular, button

I am trying to create a component in Angular 5 that will house a reusable template for a button. In different parts of my app buttons will call different functions, so I would like to be able to tell the given instance of the button what function to call. I know I could create an HTML tag for a button wherever I need it, but I was hoping I could create a reusable component so I can ensure formatting is consistent throughout the app.

Error

```
 Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in 
        [{{functioncall}}]
```

Component

```
<div id = "button">
  <button type="button" class= "btn" (click) ="{{functioncall}}" >{{label}}</button>
</div>
```

And HTML

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-button',
      templateUrl: './button.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
    })
    export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() label:string;
      @Input() functionCall:string;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you have to use the `@Output` decorator to emit some event (from child to parent)

**button.component.ts:**

```
@Input() label: string;
@Output() onClick = new EventEmitter<any>();

onClickButton(event) {
    this.onClick.emit(event);
  }
```

**button.component.html:**

```
<div id = "button">
  <button type="button" class= "btn" (click)="onClickbutton($event)" >{{label}}</button>
</div>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
label = "button label"

  functioncall(event) {
    console.log('functioncall', event);
  }
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-button (onClick)="functioncall($event)" [label]="label"></app-button>
```

See example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gghsax

Comment: I refreshed the app with a new StackBlitz link as your link doesn't work anymore (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gghsax). Furthermore I think you were missing `@Input() label: string;` as a variable declaration in `button.component.ts` (at least that error was thrown) - might be a compatiblity issue (Angular 7 now). However, awesome work!

Comment: lets say i want a icon in the button (google icons like shopping cart). How do i add that dynamically?

Comment: You can use angular Content Projection to do that. see this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imiejj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.html

Comment: Hard coded IDs like `id = "button"` should be avoid in a component. Components are meant to be reusable and IDs must be unique. Otherwise markup conformity is compromised.
One more point: I don't think wrapping each button in a div is a straight forward.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @miladfm answer, I'd recommend using the `<ng-content></ng-content>` directive here to pass content through instead of pulling in `{{label}}`, assigning the `@Output` decorator to `click` instead of `onClick`, and using the `MouseEvent` type instead of `any`. Using these changes will allow the button component to behave syntactically more like a native button when it's consumed:

**button.component.ts**

```
...
@Output() click = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

onClickButton(event) {
  this.onClick.emit(event);
}
...
```

**button.component.html**

```
<div id = "button">
  <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onClickbutton($event)">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </button>
</div>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
...
functioncall(e: MouseEvent) {
 // do stuff
}
...
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-button  (click)="functioncall($event)">Your Label Here</app-button>
```

Comment: Seems like having the event named `click` will trigger the click event twice, so I would stick to the `onClick` name.

Comment: Or, you can use `event.stopPropagation()` like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42112272/612847

Answer (score 1):

> Reusable Component - it's work for me

**I have created button as reusable component**

- **button.component.html**

  < button type="button" class= "btn" >{{label}} < / button >
- **button.component.ts**

  ```
  export class ButtonComponent {

        @Input() label: string;

        @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter<any>();

        constructor() {}

        onClickButton(event) {

            this.onClick.emit(event);

        }
   }
  ```
- **user.component.html**

  < app-button (click)="functioncall($event)" [label]="label"> < /app-button >
- **user.component.ts**

  label = 'Hello World';