# Ionic 6 : Dynamically set ngFor iterable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list of items to display in a template.

```
 <div scrollY="true" height="100px">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor=`let item of ${currentPage}` >
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">

      {{item.name}}
      <br>
      <ion-text>
      </ion-text>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-button fill="solid" id="single-restaurant" (click)="goToNextPage()">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward-circle-outline">
      </ion-icon>

    </ion-button>

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

My question is simple, yet i did not find an answer after looking for several hours.
In the ngFor directive, is it possible to use an `Input()` to set the array to iterate, depending on the page?
For example, in `HomePage` i would have an array named `home` so i would set `currentPage="home"` and expect to iterate over it.

Is it possible or do i must create a list per page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an ionic question. It is entirely angular. This question asks and answers the same concept. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826096/creating-a-reusable-button-component-in-angular

Comment: You can use a `@Input` to pass the array

Comment: Thank you, @Eliseo. Im just wondering how to pass the array inside ngFor. Backticks and ${{}} are not working.

Comment: Use neither. Everything inside the ngFor is component scope so simply  “let item of currentPage” should do (if currentPage is an array defined in your component)..

Comment: @MikeOne I cannot thank you enough, its finally working. Have a good night.